# How routing works in Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, routes, eloquent

I am hoping someone can explain why the following isn't working. Btw, I am a total noob just playing around with the concepts to learn Laravel/PHP. This is more for understanding.

I have managed to setup Laravel 9.x using Brew on a mac with Valet. Everything works by default.

I am following a tutorial but for some reason, my code is identical yet get request is not working.

I have three views:
welcome.blade,
item.blade, items.blade

The item.blade has the following:

```
<h1>This is your id: {{id}}</h1>
```

The web code is as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/item/{$id}', function($id) { 
    return view('item');
});

Route::get('/items/', function() { 
    return view('items');
});
```

Now, the confusion.. when I open the page metagigs.test/items/
The page loads fine, with the dummy text.

But when I open metagigs.test/item/1
instead of printing 1 on to the page, I get a 404 error. As if to say there isn't a page or variable output.

Someone please tell me what I have missed.

Understanding how get php laravel blade routing works. Something so simple isn't working despite having identical code to a tutorial, where it works.

Comment: because the `$` shouldn't be in the route parameter in the route definition ... https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Exactly, as @lagbox states. `Route::get('/item/{$id}', function($id) { ` should be `Route::get('/item/{id}', function($id) { `

Comment: Now I want to get my eyes checked and punch the wall! I guess this is part of the learning process. Thank you  both for the quick catch and Laravel reference to & explanation.